# How to sudo init 6 without passwd

Tags: sudo

In my `/etc/sudoers.d/csinit`, I had insert the following line, but still cannot work.

```
testcs  ALL=NOPASSWD:   /sbin/rc6, /sbin/rc5
```

I had tried this too:

```
testcs ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /sbin/rc6, /sbin/rc5
```

It will still ask for passwd when I `sudo init 6` or `init 5`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set `NOPASSWD` for `rc6` and `rc5`. If you don't want to be asked for a password for `init`, then you'll have to add those to the sudoers rule as well. Something like:

```
testcs ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /sbin/rc6, /sbin/rc5, /sbin/init [56]
```

(Since you can specify wildcards in the arguments, `[...]` matching any character in the list.)

Comment: Yeah! It's work! Thank you so much. Do you know where is the command " ifconfig e1000g1 up" file location? I tried /sbin/ifconfig but the file is for ifconfig -a command only.

Comment: @user803473 the same `/sbin/ifconfig` can be used for `ifconfig ... up` as well, as far as I know.

Comment: Since you seem to be new, you might want to consider accepting an answer if it worked for you. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers